# Remove div after fade out animation - javascript

Tags: javascript, animation

I'm trying to remove a div from the body AFTER an animation is completed, but at the moment looks like the remove happens right after the first iteration of the animation.

```
function $(el) { return document.getElementById(el); }

var divFirst = $('first');
if(divFirst)
    divFirst.addEventListener("click", addSecond);

function removeSecond()
{
    fadeOut();
    var child = $('second');
    console.log("remove called");
    child.remove();
}

function addSecond()
{
    console.log("addSecond called");
    var aContainer = document.createElement('div');
    aContainer.setAttribute('id', 'second');
    aContainer.innerHTML = "Second";
    aContainer.addEventListener("click", removeSecond);
    document.body.appendChild(aContainer);
    fadeIn();
}

function fadeIn()
{
    var secondDiv = $('second');
    if(secondDiv)
    {
        secondDiv.style.opacity ? secondDiv.style.opacity : 
            secondDiv.style.opacity = "0.0";
        if(parseFloat(secondDiv.style.opacity) <= 1)
        {
            secondDiv.style.opacity = parseFloat(secondDiv.style.opacity) + 0.05;
            setTimeout(fadeIn, 50);
        }
    }
}

function fadeOut()
{
    var secondDiv = $('second');
    if(secondDiv)
    {
        console.log(secondDiv.style.opacity);
        if(parseFloat(secondDiv.style.opacity) >0 )
        {
            secondDiv.style.opacity = parseFloat(secondDiv.style.opacity) - 0.05;
            setTimeout(fadeOut, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

Here the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ny85ckk2/
If I remove the child.remove() call, the animation continues till the end.
Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `fadeOut` is an *asynchronous* operation. When you call it, it *starts* the fade, but then the fade continues and completes asynchronously because you're using `setTimeout`. So your code after callilng `fadeOut` runs just after it starts.

To remove the element when done, remove that code and instead remove the element in `fadeOut` when done:

```
function fadeOut()
{
    var secondDiv = $('second');
    if(secondDiv)
    {
        console.log(secondDiv.style.opacity);
        if(parseFloat(secondDiv.style.opacity) >0 )
        {
            secondDiv.style.opacity = parseFloat(secondDiv.style.opacity) - 0.05;
            setTimeout(fadeOut, 50);
        }
        else                         // Added
        {                            // Added
            secondDiv.remove();      // Added
        }                            // Added
    }
}
```

Or if you want more flexibility, have `fadeOut` call a callback when done and remove the element in the callback; we do that by separating out the actual work of the fade from *starting* it:

```
function fadeOut(callback)
{
    var secondDiv = $('second');
    if (secondDiv)
    {
        doFade();
    }

    function doFade() {
        if(parseFloat(secondDiv.style.opacity) >0 )
        {
            secondDiv.style.opacity = parseFloat(secondDiv.style.opacity) - 0.05;
            setTimeout(doFade, 50);
        }
        else if (callback)
        {
            callback(secondDiv);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
function removeSecond()
{
    fadeOut(function(div) {
        div.remove();
    });
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ny85ckk2/2/)

Comment: I'm normally a fan of clean solutions, so the second option would be the best one for me, but it still does not work
http://jsfiddle.net/ny85ckk2/1/
I understand the idea, but the callback is still not called :/

Comment: @CKY: I missed that `fadeOut` was calling itself (I don't know *how* I missed that, but...). So the problem was that the call that eventually reached `0` didn't have a `callback` argument. I've fixed it above.